# Get JavaArray property from object

Tags: java, python, squish

I have a suite with python scripts to test a java application using squish.

In my test I get an object named menuObj, containing a property called items, which type is JavaArray. When I try to get that property using getattr() I get an object containing properties instead of such list (or the string containing the items in the list).

What is the proper method?

expected = [MenuItem {Project   Ctrl+Shift+D},MenuItem {System  Ctrl+Shift+M},MenuItem {Panel}]
obtained =  containing three properties.

Comment: Do you have some exemple, code or log that show this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Squish yields a [JavaArray](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ugs-javaapi.html#ugsjava-arrays) when accessing a property or calling a method that is/returns a Java array.

To access the elements in that array use the JavaArray.at(int) method:

```
items_array = swtMenuObj.items
test.log("Type of items container/array: %s" % className(items_array))
test.log("A: Item 0 text: %s" % items_array.at(0).text)
// Example output/log entries:
//  JavaArray
//  &File


items_array2 = getattr(swtMenuObj, "items")
test.log("Type of items container/array: %s" % className(items_array))
test.log("B: Item 0 text: %s" % items_array2.at(0).text)
// Example output/log entries:
//  JavaArray
//  &File
```

There should be (and for me is) no difference between using...

```
menuObj.items
```

...and...

```
getattr(menuObj, "items")
```

...and both yield an object of type JavaArray.